# How to replicate MIN and MAX in SQL

Tags: sql-server, max, min

I have an excel formula that I need to recreate in SQL:
=MIN(150,0.75*MAX(100-0-0/0.9,0))

It can be done with nested case statements, but I am using a program to generate SQL which currently does not support this:

```
select
case 
when 150 < 
    case
    when 0.75*100-0-0/0.9 < 0 
    THEN 0
    ELSE 0.75*100-0-0/0.9
    END
THEN 150
ELSE 0.75*100-0-0/0.9
END
```

Is there another way of doing this without creating a stored procedure?

Please note: I cannot use any new functionality from SQL Server 2012 or onwards.

Comment: Why would you do something like that with constants?

Comment: This is an example, the constants are actually subqueries but the query looks very confusing.

Comment: "I am using a program to generate SQL" - add it's name to the question.

Comment: It changes how you see the question. T-SQL have MAX and MIN functions that you can look up : [MIN MAX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`MIN` and `MAX` in SQL Server don't work with a delimited list; they get to minimum/maximum value for an expression across a dataset. Thus, there's no such functionality as `SELECT MIN(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC);`, instead you'd have something like:

```
WITH Numbers AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) V(N)
)
SELECT MAX(N), MIN(N)
FROM Numbers;
```

If you need to get the MAXIMUM between columns, then yes, you'll need to use a `CASE` expression. Using your data, and a bit of giuess work, this results in something like:

```
WITH Numbers AS(
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES (150,0.75,100-0-0,0.9,0)) V(A,B,C,D,E))
SELECT CASE WHEN 150 > CASE WHEN C/D > E THEN C/D
                            ELSE E END THEN 150
            ELSE CASE WHEN C/D > E THEN C/D
                      ELSE E END
        END AS MaxN
FROM Numbers;
```

The other alternative, would be to pivot your data, and get the `MAX`/`MIN` that way.  I've not posted a solution here for that one though, as we only have constants to work with, and I don't want to guess an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use subqueries with `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT MIN(Value)
FROM
  (
    SELECT 150 Value

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0.75*MAX(Value)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT 100-0-0/0.9 Value

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 0
      ) q
  ) q
```

And this query with variables

```
DECLARE
  @value1 float=100-0-0/0.9,
  @value2 float=0,
  @value3 float=150

SELECT MIN(Value)
FROM
  (
    SELECT @value3 Value

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0.75*MAX(Value)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT @value1 Value

        UNION ALL

        SELECT @value2
      ) q
  ) q
```